# How to track user response to confirm box, generated at runtime from c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get user confirmation from c# code behind file, to confirm if user wants to overwrite the existing file on server of cancel the operation but so far no luck.

this is my code :

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
   string alertMsg = @"confirm('A File already exists with the same name. \n Would you like to overwrite the existing file ?');";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Test", alertMsg, true);
}
else
{
   fuPSD.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

create

```
<asp:hiddenField id="hf" />* in the aspx file
also put on the JS location a Declaration : 

var answer=null;
```

back to server :

```
string alertMsg = @"if (confirm('A File already exists with the same name. \n Would you like to overwrite the existing file ?')==true) answer='1'; else answer='0';";
```

now on the server side : 
read  :

```
hf.value
```

Comment: What is hf here ? and how will c# get the response of confirmation on the user end ?

Comment: oh yea that completes the picture :) ... I was just discussing the same below with OnResolve .. Thanks for taking out the time Royi, I'll try it right away and will post the success.

Comment: man this doesn't seems to be working, I am trying to set the value from server site like :

string alertMsg = @"if(confirm('A File already exists with the same name. \n Would you like to overwrite the existing file ?')==true) $('#ctl00_PageBody_userConfirmation').val('1'); else $('#ctl00_PageBody_userConfirmation').val('2');";

of a <asp:hidden field, but the value is not changing.

Comment: you are not settings value from server side , you are setting value from client side and reads it in the server side. ( the confirm result should change the hf value).also check that the `answer` variable has been declared at the begining of the page ( the html  - in the JS section ( inside a script tag).

Comment: OK, so this means that a postback would require in this scenarior.

Comment: @Vishal - you set the Alert from the server side...and thats during postback... so what else ? you could have write the code in JS from the beginig of the page... and than you would have to go to the server side and run RegisterStartupScript

Comment: I think I am still not with you here, according to you, I should write a JS function on the top of ASPX page :
        function setValue() {
}
which I am not sure what will do, and then I have set-up a <asp:fiddenField below in the form, now when user browse the file from AsyncFileUplaod tool I gonna register the same script, which will basically display the confirmation box to user and set the Variable to 1 , (which I am not sure have been declared where) and then how do we gonna set the value for the HiddenField, I know its getting a bit messy but I am not able to get you idea.

Answer (score 0):

That code will pop up the message if the file exists and save it if it doesn't.

But you will need to take some action on the confirm dialog result on the client side and either trigger a postback or some other server call to perform the operation in the case of the override.

Comment: Hmm. true, so this means that the target I am trying to achieve is not possible by c# code alone, I'll have to manage script at client site and track the response by making post-back, is that true ??

Comment: @Vishal Well, you're already using JavaScript/DOM, so...  But you can do it completely in server-side-generated HTML/CSS with hidden form elements and stateful forms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your JavaScript registration will ask the user to confirm to overwrite the file   *after* the next page loads.  This then poses the issue of telling whether the user confirmed or denied from the server since you're confirm with be client side.

In the past I've used a hidden field to toggle true/false to show a popup from the server side. This gives me the ability to wire up the events to a delegate on the code behind(I.e make my own confirm box with my own buttons). You can still do this without it by I found that it leads to a lot of messy and hard to follow script like callin __doPostback manually.

Comment: Yes thats true, So how about this, I'll putt a hidden text box on the asp.net page and as per user response to confirm box I'll set a value into that and then I'll procces by reading the values in c# code for the same text box, if its 1 then overwrite the file, you think that will work out ?? I know calling _doPostBack manually makes the code very messy..